k8s enable env variable only for the first pod deployed
I have a StatefulSet of 3 instances to create db cluster.
I need to set an env variable only on the first pod to initialize the cluster.
I tried to use initContainers but it doen't work.
This is an example of my code:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: galera-ss
  namespace: mon-zabbix
spec:
  serviceName: galera-ss
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: galera-ss
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: galera-ss
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: volume-permissions
        image: busybox
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami/mariadb && chmod -R 775 /bitnami/mariadb
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-datadir
          mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb
      - name: bootstrap
        image: busybox
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          if [[ $(hostname | awk -F '-' '{print $NF}') == 0 ]]; then
            export MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_BOOTSTRAP="yes"
          else
            sleep 60
          fi
        env:
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_FORCE_SAFETOBOOTSTRAP
          value: "no"                                 # default for other pods
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_BOOTSTRAP
          value: "no"                                 # default for other pods
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-datadir
          mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb
      containers:
      - name: galera
        image: bitnami/mariadb-galera:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: secrets
                key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_NAME
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: CLUSTER_NAME
                name: configmap
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_ADDRESS
          value: "gcomm://galera-ss-cluster:4567"
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_MARIABACKUP_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: secrets
                key: XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD
        - name: MARIADB_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_DATABASE
                name: configmap
        - name: MARIADB_USER
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_USER
                name: secrets
        - name: MARIADB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: secrets
                key: MARIADB_PASSWORD
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-datadir
          mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mysql-datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi

but when I run it, I don't see these env variables set in the pods.
If it isn't possible, can I split the pod creation in two, one for the first and the second for the others (2+), but in this case, on the second conf can I index starting from 1 and not from 0?
Where am I'm wronging?

why did you close my question?
you linked to existing question closed too, how can users help me if both are closed?

a) This question is about software configuration, not development. b) Reposting
is generally being frowned upon c) Be more concise on explanations and less verbose on code.. Voted to leave closed. Please amend your question.

Hi @syck thanks for the reply.
a) the question is on the development (how can set in k8s env variables) not on software conf
b) this was my first question, closed and I reopened another one
c) I'll do

@MarcoFerrara, I've seen some questions closed because the CLOSER did not believe the question was a programming question.   While the CLOSER was correct, the activity that the programmer was performing was part of the job of development.  I'm new to the role of editing and re-opening questions so I need to better understand (a) What is the SO rule, and (b) where do people post questions that are configuration questions.
